# Processing java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: processing

Not sure what I've done, but all of a sudden I started getting the following error, when I'm trying to use any render   size(800, 500, **P2D**); or P3D.
I'm using Processing 2.0b4

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: jogamp.opengl.macosx.cgl.MacOSXOnscreenCGLDrawable cannot be cast to javax.media.opengl.GLFBODrawable
    at processing.opengl.PGL$PGLListener.display(PGL.java:2454)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:373)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:358)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$7.run(GLCanvas.java:983)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:655)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:594)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$8.run(GLCanvas.java:996)
    at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:193)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:449)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.paint(GLCanvas.java:499)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(RepaintArea.java:276)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:241)
    at apple.awt.ComponentModel.handleEvent(ComponentModel.java:263)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4790)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4544)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:635)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: jogamp.opengl.macosx.cgl.MacOSXOnscreenCGLDrawable cannot be cast to javax.media.opengl.GLFBODrawable
    at jogamp.common.awt.AWTEDTExecutor.invoke(AWTEDTExecutor.java:58)
    at jogamp.opengl.awt.AWTThreadingPlugin.invokeOnOpenGLThread(AWTThreadingPlugin.java:103)
    at jogamp.opengl.ThreadingImpl.invokeOnOpenGLThread(ThreadingImpl.java:205)
    at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invokeOnOpenGLThread(Threading.java:172)
    at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:191)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:449)
    at processing.opengl.PGL.requestDraw(PGL.java:870)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.requestDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:1523)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2006)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: jogamp.opengl.macosx.cgl.MacOSXOnscreenCGLDrawable cannot be cast to javax.media.opengl.GLFBODrawable
    at processing.opengl.PGL$PGLListener.display(PGL.java:2454)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:373)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:358)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$7.run(GLCanvas.java:983)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:655)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:594)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$8.run(GLCanvas.java:996)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:199)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:633)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)

Comment: so if you wrote a Processing sketch that was just `void setup() {
  size(800, 500, P2D);
}

void draw() { 
}` you would get this error?

Answer (score 0):

P2D and P3D are changed to use OPENGL in Processing 2.0. There are a lot of bugs about that. So you should try the latest beta release.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the latest processing release which is 3.3.3.